# Sending JSON from jQuery to PHP to edit a text file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

What I'm trying to do is the following:
I want to send a JSON object from my jQuery code to the PHP file on my server.
I want the PHP file to append this JSON object to my text file.

**The problem:**

I'm struggeling with the PHP file. I'm sending the data and I need the PHP to save that data in a variable so that I can write it into a textfile. The problem is that it doesn't do that. The post I make, apparently, has no content (it just shows `array()`).

My jQuery code:

```
var username = "";
var password = "";
var url = window.location.href;
var title = document.title;
var detailsArray = {title : [{
                    "title" : title,
                    "url" : url, 
                    "username" : username, 
                    "password" : password
                    }]
                    };

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 17) {
        console.log(detailsArray);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://......./Server.php",
          data: detailsArray,
          success: function(data) {
              console.log("Data sent!"+data);
          }
        });
    }
});
```

My PHP code:

```
$dataToBeInserted = $_POST;
$file = "JSON.json";

//Open the file with read/write permission or show text
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
$stat = fstat($fh);

//Remove the last 2 characters from the JSON file
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-2);

//Add the data from $dataToBeInserted to the file
echo fwrite($file, $dataToBeInserted );

//Close the file
fclose($fh);
```

This PHP file gives a couple of warning/errors:

`Array ( )`

`Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in Server.php on line 17`

`Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in Server.php on line 19`

**What am I doing wrong here?** I'm not used to PHP so there's probably a bunch of errors in there, but I thought the jQuery side was okay.

Comment: Doesn't fwrite need $fh instead of file? http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: In your ajax code block, try adding the option: `dataType: 'json',` (don't forget: the capital T in dataType, enclose json in quotes, the trailing comma)

Comment: @gibberish: I just tried that but it still gives the `Array ()`. Im starting to think its the way I set up my `detailsArray` but Im not sure what I've done wrong there.

Comment: Scratch that, it must be something else. I just used the code xcezzz gave me and it's reading the JSON perfectly fine! This means I have something weird in my PHP file thats not supposed to be there, but I'll figure it out. Thank you for trying (and helping) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first your fwrite($file) should be fwrite($fh).. you have to write to the file handle returned by fopen... not the string name of the file.

```
$dataToBeInserted = $_POST;
$file = "JSON.json";

//Open the file with read/write permission or show text
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
$stat = fstat($fh);

//Remove the last 2 characters from the JSON file
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-2);

//Add the data from $dataToBeInserted to the file
echo fwrite($fh, $dataToBeInserted );

//Close the file
fclose($fh);
```

but then your JSON file is incomplete/corrupt. since you removed the 2 characters, but never added them back.

honestly the easy way to solve this would be

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('JSON.json'));
if (!$data) $data = array();
array_push($data, $_POST);
file_put_contents('JSON.json', json_encode($data);
```

but this will get very expensive IO/resource wise the larger it gets

other method.... see comments

```
$dataToBeInserted = $_POST;
$file = "JSON.json";

//Open the file with read/write permission or show text
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
$stat = fstat($fh);

//Remove the last 2 characters from the JSON file
//ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-2);

//Add the data from $dataToBeInserted to the file with a comma before it if there is data in file already.
if ($stat['size'] != 0) $append = ",";
echo fwrite($fh, $append . json_encode($dataToBeInserted) );

//Close the file
fclose($fh);
```

now to read it..

```
$data = file_get_contents('JSON.json');
$dataArray = json_decode('[' . $data  . ']');
```

so now each time we write to the file we put a comma, then when we read it we wrap it in brackets so it's an array of the writes we have been doing.

While this wont be as resource intensive write-wise it will be read wise... but thats because you want everything in one file.

Comment: You were right about the error message, `$file` was supposed to be `$fh`. The resources will be a problem eventually because the JSON file will end up being very long. Is there a (less) easy to do this?

Comment: That comes down to how will this data be used/loaded? Can you just dump each request to an individual file in a directory based off timestamp or date("Y-m-dH-i-s") type format? then there is no resource issue on a big ol file, but then how will the data be read back?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it has to be in a single file. I'll eventually be doing things with Arduino, which has VERY limited resources.

Comment: well reading in a big ol file will still be a problem on that kind of platform... but I will update the answer with another way if you have control over the way it is read...

Comment: hope that all makes sense... this way it's mostly valid JSON in the file and just needs a bracket burrito to be read properly

Comment: This works pretty well! There are some minor things that I'm adding to the code, like JSON_PRETTY_PRINT and JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, some { bracket issues, but other than that, thank you very much! You've been so much help! :D